Flask WebSocket Messages not emitted
I want to use a WebSocket to stream dummy data (a random 4-char string) to a div on a HTML page, using Python with the Flask webserver. The source for both Python and HTML follows.
main7.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import random
import string

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index7.html')

def generate_random_chars():
    while True:
        random_chars = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=4))
        socketio.emit('update', random_chars)
        socketio.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.start_background_task(target=generate_random_chars)
    socketio.run(app, host='localhost', port=5000, debug=True)

index7.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flask WebSocket Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="random-chars">Waiting for updates...</div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.0/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        const socket = io();
        socket.on('update', function(data) {
            document.getElementById('random-chars').innerText = data;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

The page is served with no error and there appears to be a WebSocket connection established but after that, there none of the emitted messages appear in the network traffic.
There are also no error messages from the Flask debug output, or the DevTools console.
 * Restarting with watchdog (inotify)
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 136-937-281
(210008) wsgi starting up on http://127.0.0.1:5000
(210008) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 49994)
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2024 19:48:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 640 0.003211
(210008) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 49998)
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2024 19:48:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 293 0.001261
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2024 19:49:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 611 0.002471
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2024 19:49:04] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P6V2cR7 HTTP/1.1" 200 278 0.000470
(210008) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 42628)
(210008) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 42634)
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2024 19:49:04] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P6V2cRC&sid=WyHUScU-T8s22PT_AAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 219 0.001391
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2024 19:49:04] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P6V2cRD&sid=WyHUScU-T8s22PT_AAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 213 0.000228
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2024 19:49:04] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P6V2cRM&sid=WyHUScU-T8s22PT_AAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 181 0.000252
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2024 19:49:48] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=WyHUScU-T8s22PT_AAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 0 43.720072
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2024 19:49:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 611 0.001028
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2024 19:49:48] "GET /socket.io/?...


Any insight into the problem appreciated!

At a minimum I would wait for the page to load before connecting from the client and wait for the socket to connect before emitting from the server. It may not be the source of the issue you describe but those are race conditions that are easily avoided.

Thank you @Woodford, starting the emit task only after the WebSocket connection is established seems to have fixed the issue of no data emission.

The solution was to avoid the race conditions pointed out by user Woodford, in particular to start the emit task only after the WebSocket connection is established.
Below is the modified working code with extra network status reporting on the client side:
main.py
from datetime import datetime
import logging
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def generate_time_str():
    while True:
        time_str = str(datetime.now())
        logger.info(f"Emitting: {time_str}")
        socketio.emit('update', time_str)
        socketio.sleep(1)

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    logger.info("Client connected")
    socketio.start_background_task(target=generate_time_str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='localhost', port=5000, debug=True)

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flask WebSocket Test</title>
    <style>
        .error { color: red; }
        .connected { color: green; }
        .disconnected { color: orange; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="server-data"></div>
    <div id="network-status">Connecting to server...</div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.0/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const socket = io({
                reconnection: true,
                reconnectionAttempts: Infinity,
                reconnectionDelay: 1000,
                reconnectionDelayMax: 5000,
                timeout: 20000,
            });
            const randomCharsDiv = document.getElementById('server-data');
            const networkStatusDiv = document.getElementById('network-status');
            
            function updateNetworkStatus(message, className) {
                networkStatusDiv.textContent = message;
                networkStatusDiv.className = className;
            }

            socket.on('connect', function() {
                console.log('Connected to server');
                updateNetworkStatus('Connected to server', 'connected');
            });

            socket.on('update', function(data) {
                console.log('Received update:', data);
                randomCharsDiv.textContent = data;
            });

            socket.on('disconnect', function(reason) {
                console.log('Disconnected from server:', reason);
                updateNetworkStatus('Disconnected from server', 'disconnected');
            });

            socket.on('connect_error', function(error) {
                console.error('Connection error:', error);
                updateNetworkStatus('Error connecting to server', 'error');
            });

            socket.on('reconnect_attempt', function(attemptNumber) {
                console.log('Attempting to reconnect:', attemptNumber);
                updateNetworkStatus(`Attempting to reconnect (${attemptNumber})`, 'disconnected');
            });

            socket.on('reconnect', function(attemptNumber) {
                console.log('Reconnected on attempt:', attemptNumber);
                updateNetworkStatus('Reconnected to server', 'connected');
            });

            socket.on('reconnect_error', function(error) {
                console.error('Reconnection error:', error);
                updateNetworkStatus('Error reconnecting to server', 'error');
            });

            socket.on('reconnect_failed', function() {
                console.error('Failed to reconnect');
                updateNetworkStatus('Failed to reconnect to server', 'error');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

